# how to check if all data match a value in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

my collection is

```
{
id:1,
 "codes": [
            1,
            0,
            0
        ]
}
```

i have to check if all values in codes match 1
i tried the following

```
 value: {
                    $max: {
                        $cond: [{
                            $and: [{ $eq: ["$data.count_3", 1] },

                            ]
                        },
                            0,
                            1]
                    }
                },
```

this.data.count_3 has code Values i,e [1,0,0]

but its not working fine.am i using the variable correctly.please help.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may compare arrays before / after `$filter`ing.
Change this condition `"$eq": ["$$this", 1]` to filter only valid items.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      value: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$codes",
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$codes",
                  cond: {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this",
                      1
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OVI62d8-O5K)